# Ensuring socket messages were sent using flask-socketio, redis

Tags: python, redis, flask-socketio

I have a flask-socketio server running on multiple pods, using redis as a message queue. I want to ensure that emits from external processes reach their destination 100% of the time, or to know when they have failed.

When process A emits an event to a socket that's connected to process B, the event goes through the message queue to process B, to the client. Is there any way I can intercept the outgoing emit on process B? Ideally i'd then use a worker to check after a few seconds if the message reached the client (via a confirm event emitted from the client) or it will be emitted again.

This code runs on process A:

```
@app.route('/ex')
def ex_route():
    socketio.emit('external', {'text': f'sender: {socket.gethostname()}, welcome!'}, room='some_room')
    return jsonify(f'sending message to room "some_room" from {socket.gethostname()}')
```

This is the output from process A

```
INFO:socketio.server:emitting event "external" to some_room [/]
INFO:geventwebsocket.handler:127.0.0.1 - - [2019-01-11 13:33:44] "GET /ex HTTP/1.1" 200 177 0.003196
```

This is the output from process B

```
INFO:engineio.server:9aab2215a0da4816a45e3fdc1e449fce: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["external",{"text":"sender: *******, welcome!"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no mechanism to do what you ask, unfortunately.

I think you basically have two approaches to go about this:

1. Always run your emits from the main server(s). If you need to emit from an auxiliary process, use an IPC mechanism to notify the server so that it can run the emit on its behalf. And now you can use callbacks.
2. Ignore the callbacks, and instead have the client acknowledge receipt of the event by emitting back to the server.

Adding callback support for auxiliary processes should not be terribly difficult, by the way. I never needed that functionality myself and you are the first to ask about it. Maybe I should look into that at some point.

**Edit**: after some thought, I came up with a 3rd option:

You can connect your external process to the server as a client, instead of using the "emit-only" option. If this process is a client, it can emit an event to the server, which in turn the server can relay to the external client. When the client replies to the server, the server can once again relay the response to the external process, which is not another client and has full send and receive capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Using IPC is not very robust, especially in case of server receiving a lot of requests there might be an issue where you receive a message and don't retranslate it and it's vital.

Use either celery or zmq or redis itself for interconnect. The most natural is using socketio itself like mentioned by Miguel as it's already waiting for the requests has the environment and can emit anytime.

I've used a greenlet hack over threads - where greenlet is lighter than threads and runs in the same environment allowing it to send the message while your main thread awaits socket in non-blocking mode. Basically you write a thread, then apply eventlet or gevent to the whole code via monkeypatching and the thread becomes a greenlet - an inbetween function call. You put a sleep on it so it doesn't hog all resources and you have your sender because greenlets share environment easily, they are not bound by io, just cpu (which is the same for threads in Python but greenlets are even more lightweight due to no OS-level context change at all).

But as soon as CPU load increased I switched over to client/server. Imbuing IPC would require massive rewrites from the ground up.